# Probability frequency distribution with window size 0.1 increments wrong bucket

Tags: perl, range

I did not use only the equal operator to do so, because the user input for the window size can vary.

```
print"Enter the window size";
my $p_win=<>;#window size can vary according to the user's requirement
chomp($p_win);

my $x=0;
my $y=$x+$p_win;
my $i=0;
my @count;
#initializing the value of the count for all the ranges as 0
while($x ne 1)
{
    $count[$i]=0;
print "$x>= p >$y\t$count[$i]=\n";<>;
    $x=$x+$p_win;
    $y=$y+$p_win;
    $i++;
}
$count[$i]=0;# count where the value of D is NA and E is 1
my $na=$i;  

open(F1,"new.txt");
my $flag=0;
my (@a,@b);
while(<F1>)
{
    if($flag == 0)
    {
        $flag++;#first line of the new.txt
    }
    else
    {
        chomp($_);
        my @a=split(/\t/,$_);
        $x=0;
        $y=$x+$p_win;
        for($i=0; $i<scalar(@count)-1; $i++)
        {
            if($a[3] eq 'NA')
            {
                $count[$na]++;                  
                $i=scalar(@count);
            }
            else
            {
                if($x le $a[4] && $a[4]<$y)
                {
                    $count[$i]++;               
                    $i=scalar(@count);
                }
                my $t=scalar(@count)-2;
                if($i== $t)
                {               
                    if($a[4] eq $y)
                    {
                        $count[$i]++;
                    }           
                }
            }
            $x=$x+$p_win;
            $y=$y+$p_win;
        }

    }
}
```

`new.txt` is in the given format. The frequency distribution of `e` is to be generated:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   2   4   5   0.1
1   2   3   4   0.2
1   2   4   5   0.9
1   2   3   4   0
1   2   4   NA  1
1   2   3   4   0.2
1   2   4   5   0.3
1   2   3   4   0.9
1   2   4   5   0.8
1   2   3   4   0.7
1   2   4   5   0.6
1   2   3   4   0.5
1   2   4   5   0.4
1   2   3   4   0.2
1   2   4   5   0.1
1   2   3   4   1
1   2   4   5   0.9
1   2   3   4   0.8
1   2   4   NA  1
1   2   3   4   0.4
1   2   4   5   0.5
1   2   3   4   0.2
1   2   4   5   0.3
1   2   3   4   0.1
```

The output is:

```
0 >= p > 0.1    1
0.1 >= p > 0.2  3
0.2 >= p > 0.3  6#count of 0.3-0.4 is also added here
0.3 >= p > 0.4  0
0.4 >= p > 0.5  2
0.5 >= p > 0.6  2
0.6 >= p > 0.7  1
0.7 >= p > 0.8  1
0.8 >= p > 0.9  2
0.9 >= p >= 1   4
NA 1     2
```

Comment: The `<>` at the end of your print statement is unnecessary.

Comment: You are missing the code which prints out the results.

Comment: Your problem is likely due to the `while ( $x ne 1 )` which might not be true due to floating point rounding.  You should use `!=` for numeric comparison, instead of `ne` which is a string comparison.  Maybe change it to `while ( $x <= 1 )`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's always a bad idea to use string comparators like `eq`, `ne` and `lt` for comparing numeric values. It makes Perl convert the values into a string and compare the characters on-by-one instead of just comparing the numbers directly.

Also, you can never compare floating-point numbers for equality, because a value like 0.1 cannot be represented precisely in Intel floating point. This applies especially when the values are the result of a series of additions because adding, for instance, ten copies of 0.1 together will result in ten times the error that each one of those values had

You could allow an arbitrary margin of error, such as

```
if ( abs($x - $y) < 0.00001 ) { ... }
```

but that's clumsy and inexpressive

By far the best way with sequences like this is to keep all the arithmetic in integer format. In my answer below I've changed from using *window size* `$p_win` to *number of windows* `$num_win`, which is always an integer. Then the array index `$i` for a given probability `$p` is just `$i = int $p * $num_win`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print "Enter the number of windows: ";
my $num_win = <>;

if ( $num_win and $num_win =~ /\S/ ) {
    chomp $num_win;
}
else {
    $num_win = 10;  # Default to ten windows
}

printf "\nCalculating for %d Windows\n", $num_win;

my @count;
$_ = 0 for @count[0 .. $num_win];

open my $fh, '<', 'new.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    next if $. == 1;
    next unless /\S/;

    my @fields = split;
    my $i;

    if ( $fields[3] eq 'NA' ) {
        $i = $#count;
    }
    else {
        $i = int $fields[4] * $num_win;
        --$i if $i == $#count;
    }

    ++$count[$i];
}

for my $i (0 .. $#count ) {

    if ( $i < $#count ) {
        printf "%.2f <= p < %.2f  count %d\n", $i/$num_win, ($i+1)/$num_win, $count[$i];
    }
    else {
        printf "%.2f (NA)         count %d\n", $i/$num_win, $count[$i];
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Enter the number of windows: 
Calculating for 10 Windows
0.00 <= p < 0.10  count 1
0.10 <= p < 0.20  count 3
0.20 <= p < 0.30  count 4
0.30 <= p < 0.40  count 2
0.40 <= p < 0.50  count 2
0.50 <= p < 0.60  count 2
0.60 <= p < 0.70  count 1
0.70 <= p < 0.80  count 1
0.80 <= p < 0.90  count 2
0.90 <= p < 1.00  count 4
1.00 (NA)         count 2
```